# XML Source to OLE Destination in SSIS not inserting foreign keys

Tags: ssis

I have SSIS package which conains XML Source that gives output to two OLE DB Destination, first one is the parent table and second destination is the child table. Both are eanbled with Identity Specification. When i run the package in the parent table primary key auto increments but in the child table the foreign key is not inserted (only null). Any suggestions please
Representation of my DataFlow

```
> XML Source  ---------> OLE DB Destination (Mapped to Parent table)
>             |
>             ---------> OLE DB Destination (Mapped to child table)
```

Comment: how do you know what ParentId to insert in the child table?  Does  the child table insert happen at the same time as the parent?  Can you post an image of the executed task to aid the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, we can do it directly. So the steps i did was insert the xml data directly to flat table, then created a sql execute task and ran insert, update scripts to tranform into real tables